# Python replace indentation with period

Tags: python, replace, indentation

I am trying to replace the indentation in a file with periods, but my script is replacing all of the spaces in indented lines, not just the indentation.

```
lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in open('test0.py', 'r')]   #create line array
for l in lines:
    #print l
    data = l
    while data.startswith(" "):
        data=data.replace(data[0], ".")  #replace start of line with "."
    print data
```

Here is what the script incorrectly outputs

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import BaseHTTPServer
import ssl

class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
....def.do_GET(self):
........if.self.path.==.'/':
............self.path.=.'test.html'
........return.SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

Handler = MyRequestHandler
server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('192.168.2.3', 8080), Handler)
server.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(server.socket, certfile='server.pem', server_side=True)
server.serve_forever()
```

I am trying to leave the rest of the spaces in the indented line alone.

Comment: I'm seeing some spaces in that output... Also, have you considered a less naive approach that just a call to `replace`?

Comment: @Darkhogg There is spaces in the lines that were not not indented, but there is no spaces in the indented lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, can't think of a clever solution, so how about this:

```
rhs = data.lstrip()
print '.' * (len(data) - len(rhs)) + rhs
```

(Seeing how top performance is probably not terribly important here)

Answer (score 3):

```
import re


PATTERN = re.compile(r"^( +)", re.MULTILINE)


with open("test0.py") as file:
    content = file.read()

content = PATTERN.sub(lambda m: "."*len(m.group(1)), content)
print(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line inside the while loop incorrectly replaces all spaces with colons.

Change

`data=data.replace(data[0], ".")`

to:

`data="."+data[1:]`

Comment: This answer explains the reason the original code doesn't work (`replace` replaces _all_ occurrences of the first argument...)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data.replace("\t", ".")
```

It will replace all tabulated indendts by a dot. If a dot isn't enough, as a tabulation indent has always the same length you can increase the number of dots in your replace call:

```
data.replace("\t", ".......")
```